NSIS Progress Bar Appearing Behind Status Bar in Korean,Japanese and Chinese OS Languages
I'm working on an NSIS installer and encountered an issue where the progress bar appears behind the bottom bar (status bar) when the installer is running in Korean,Japanese and Chinese OS Languages.
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $1 $0 1004
System::Call UxTheme::SetWindowTheme(ir1,w"",w"")
SendMessage $1 ${PBM_SETBARCOLOR} 0 0x0083FF ;BGR format
SendMessage $1 ${CCM_SETBKCOLOR} 0 0xFFFFFF
System::Call 'user32::SetWindowPos(i$1,i,i 0u,i 353u,i 541u,i 100u,i 0x04 )' ; move | size

How can I modify the script to ensure the progress bar is correctly positioned and visible above the status bar in all languages?

Where are you calling this code? Is it an attempt to fix the issue or something else?

I have created a custom nsis installer with a progess bar but the progress bas is not visible in CJK OS language

A full example that reproduces the problem is required...
